# Problem when booting debian

Tags: installation, debian, mbr

I am trying to setup a home server running Debian. I set up the partitions manually using gparted with the drive connected to a usb caddy on another PC, used debbootstrap to get the  base file system. Then I booted the PC from a Live USB, chrooted into the / partition and installed grub2.

However now when I boot, before it gets to grub2 I get a message saying MBR 2FA:

I have read that this means it is asking where to boot from: partition (2), (f)loppy or (a)uto. My keyboard at this point does not work as I don't think it is supported in the BIOS, so I can't select anything.

Does anyone know how to stop this happening?

Comment: Sorry I can't help but ask why not just use the installer?

Comment: Ironicly enough I had a problem where the installer wasn't letting me select where to install grub and installing to the wrong place. Then my manual way of doing it, I did exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I was installing grub to the wrong device.